# Image upload works perfectly on emulator but does not work when i use it on my phone

Tags: android

Hi guys from past 8 days i have been searching for the solution of this error

Let me explain the problem first

i am creating a application where user are allowed to upload their image

until now i was testing all my code on Emulator everything is working fine their

but when I installed it on my mobile phone for some reason the image upload doesn't seem to work

the logic which i am using is in the following code

```
  public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();

            String fileNameSegments[] = imgDecodableString.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
            params.put("filename", fileName);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
    uploadImage();
}

public void uploadImage() {
    // When Image is selected from Gallery
    if (imgDecodableString != null && !imgDecodableString.isEmpty()) {
        prgDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        // Convert image to String using Base64
        encodeImagetoString();
        // When Image is not selected from Gallery
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "You must select image from gallery before you try to upload",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// AsyncTask - To convert Image to String
public void encodeImagetoString() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

            // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
            params.put("image", encodedString);
            // Trigger Image upload
            triggerImageUpload();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

public void triggerImageUpload() {
    makeHTTPCall();
}

// Make Http call to upload Image to Php server
public void makeHTTPCall() {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    // Don't forget to change the IP address to your LAN address. Port no as well.
    client.post("http://example.com/upload_image.php",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                // When the response returned by REST has Http
                // response code '200'
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.dismiss();
                    String str= response.toString();
                    pp.setText(str);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // When the response returned by REST has Http
                // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                // '500' or '403' etc
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {
                    // Hide Progress Dialog

                    // When Http response code is '404'
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Requested resource not found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code is '500'
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Something went wrong at server end",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : "
                                        + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

}

And moreover their is no error in the LOGCAT 
if you guys can help me with this problem i would be very grateful

and can you also specify the reason why does this happens that the app works fine on emulator and not on mobile

UPDATE

forgot to add my php Code

```
    <?php

    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    $filename = time()."_".$filename;
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploads/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}
    echo 'my web address/uploads/'.$filename;
?>
```

Comment: is a localhost that you are using as a server?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie No actually its a hosting service Hostinger.com

Comment: the my web address part is www.example.com/uploads/ .$filename

Comment: Can you say us what you have for status on your server? Do you have access to the console of it ?

Comment: yes sir @LaurentMeyer  and its live thats when i use the android emulator its able to upload it but when i use my phone it does not its weird  right

Comment: It cannot be in theory... So what do you have for status code on the server when you upload with the phone ?

Comment: well sir the reply which i get from server is

 "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code

Comment: Probably the Bitmap you tried to decode was too big. Most phones have a small heap size while their camera is able to capture huge images of a few megapixels. For example, a 10 Megapixel photo at 32 bits-per-pixel color creates a 40 Megabytes Bitmap. I don't get why you uncompress the jpeg to recompress it to PNG though, you could send the image file as-is.

Comment: @BladeCoder That might be it thanks brother was curious to know the cause at least solved the issue finally  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i found the answer

i just changed this

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }
```

to this

```
public void encodeImagetoString() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {

            };

                       @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                        options);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
                int width_tmp = options.outWidth, height_tmp = options.outHeight;

                int scale = 4;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, o2);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                // Encode Image to String
                encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                return "";
            }
```

But i still cant figure out whats going wrong why  is it uploading on emulator but not on mobile if any one has the answer to it please do let me know